# bounded linear transformations

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, linear-transformations

I am trying to show that a linear map from a field  to a vector space $W$ is bounded.

Here is is what I know:

Since $\mathbb{F}$ is either $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, it is finite dimensional because in both cases, we have a basis consisting of one element.

Suppose $f_{1}$ is a basis for our field. Then for $f=a_{1}f_{1}$ we have:

\begin{align}
\|Tf\|_{W}&=\|Ta_{1}f_{1}\|_{W}\\
&=\|a_{1}Tf_{1}\|_{W}\\
&=|a_{1}|\|Tf_{1}\|_{W}\\
&=|a_{1}||f_{1}|\|T(1)\|_{W}\\
\end{align}

And here I am stuck. I need to show that $\|Tf\|_{V}<\infty$, but I am confused because the the a's are real numbers and hence unbounded. Any insight would be appreciated..thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are done. You have that $|a_1f_1|=\|a_1f_1\|=\|f\|$. So you have
$$
\|Tf\|_V=\|T(1)\|_V\,\|f\|,
$$
showing that $T$ is bounded and $\|T\|\leq\|T(1)\|_V$.

Comment: Thank you, but I am still wondering one thing. Why is it that $\|T(1)\|_{V}$ can't equal $\infty$?

Comment: Because that's not what a norm does. If you have an element with "infinite norm", then you don't have a normed space.

Answer (score 0):

$$\|Tf\|_V = \|T(f1)\|_V = \|fT(1)\|_V = |f|\|T(1)\|_V = c|f|$$ where $c := \|T(1)\|_V$. Thus $\|Tf\|_V \leq c|f|$ for any $f \in \mathbb F$, which means that $T$ is [bounded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_operator).